# Crystal Reports - Change Language

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I have installed the Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2010 but the interface language was installed in Portuguese (and also all error messages). How could I change the interface language to English? I do not remember to have been asked for in the installation.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you had any luck with this?

Comment: @Luis Unfortunately not!